# Is there an evolutionary reason why so many white matter tracts decussate in the brainstem and spinal chord?

Tags: brain, neurology

From a developmental perspective, I would tend to assume that it would be much simpler for the fibers descending from (for instance) the pyramidal tracts, superior cerebellar peduncles, or ascending from the dorsal columns to remain ipsilateral. Can anybody think of a reason why some white matter tracts developed contralaterally?